# Перечисления(Enum) Java

Tags: java

Например, у меня есть класс Person, у которого есть конструктор

```
public Person(String name, String gender) {
this.name = name;
this.gender = gender;
}
```

Мне сказали, что лучше использовать Enum тип для поля gender, т.е мужчина и женщина.

```
enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Но при вызове конструктора класса с передачей в параметр поля Gender - будет явная ошибка, если не привести к строке через toString().

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было не приводить явно к строке, а описать это при создании Enum перечисления

Answer (score 5):

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private Gender gender;

    Person(String name, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Person("Vasya", Gender.MALE);
    }
}

enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Java - язык со строгой типизацией. Если у вас поле типа enum, то в него никак нельзя засунуть string. Ну, разумеется, enum тоже является классом, просто немного специфическим, но , как и в любом классе , тут можно переопределить метод toString, прикрутить иной костыль каким-либо чудо-методом. но тогда вопрос - а зачем вам вообще enum , если вы у него постоянно пытаетесь вызвать  toString или соверишить другой танец с бубном. toString - очень медленный метод, а прелести enum  именно в том, что все его поля final со всеми вытекающими: он быстрый , работает в многопоточной среде, даже сравнивают его ==, а не методом equals. Своими преобразованиями вы убьете всю выгоду. Если у вас поле типа enum , то и в конструктор передавайте enum, иначе смысла в этом никакого.

Comment: Ну,разумеется, это очепятка, простите, всего не доглядишь. Сейчас подправим

Comment: Все-таки toString у перечисления объявлен как `return name;` где name - поле задаваемое в конструкторе... Что тут медленного-то?..